# Problemas com login no codeigniter após trocar de windows para ubuntu

Tags: codeigniter

Estou com problemas, eu havia criado uma aplicação em codeigniter em meu localhost, tinha o sistema operacional windows 10 instalado e usava o Wamp Server instalado, porem formatei meu computador e instalei o ubuntu linux como sistema operacional e instalei o Xampp na maquina, porem agora não consigo fazer login na aplicação, testei os models e controllers para ver e esta tudo certo, nos teste via que ao autenticar o email e senha esta retornando o usuario normalmente porem nao esta adicionando na session.

Segue codigo do controller (Login.php):

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
        if($this->session->userdata('isLoggedIn')) {
            redirect('/painel/acesso');
        } else {
            $this->show_login();
        }
    }

    function login_user() {

    $this->load->model('Login_model');

    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password  = sha1($this->input->post('password'));

        $usuario = $this->Login_model->logar($email, $password);

        if($usuario){
            $this->session->set_userdata('isLoggedIn', $usuario);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Login efetuado com sucesso, seja bem vindo.');
            redirect('/painel/acesso');

        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','E-mail ou senha invalidas');
            redirect('/login');
        }
    }
```

Segue codigo do Model (Login_model.php):

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model {

    public function logar($email, $password){
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $usuario = $this->db->get('user')->row_array();
        return $usuario;
    }

}
```

**OBS:** Lembrando que este erro começou quando migrei para o Ubuntu

---

entao, só que eu dei uma olhada no arquivo **"/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini"** e na linha **session.save_path="/opt/lampp/temp/"** esta salvando os arquivos de sessao nesta pasta, pelo menos é o que eu entendo, nesta pasta **/opt/lampp/temp/** estão sendo salvos os arquivos com nome parecido a este :

**ci_session03d59bd3750fd71051bf4ad894e98a20**

Porem percebi que estão vindo com o sinal de bloqueado, e não é possivel de ler, a nao ser que eu de permissao no terminal com **"sudo chmod -R 777 temp"**, dai eu consigo ler e o arquivo.veja que retorna sim com a mensagem de **sucesso:success|s:43:"Login efetuado com sucesso"**, seja bem vindo."Porem nao entendo porque esta sendo bloqueado

Comment: Muito provável que seja os arquivos de sessão que não estão sendo gravados. Dê uma olhada no config.php dentro de config na linha onde tem a configuração do $config['sess_save_path']. Realize a configuração desse PATH ou, no php.ini informe a configuração do session.save_path. Normalmente fica dentro de /tmp.